# Change Keyboard Shortcut on Texshop

Tags: texshop

- In Texshop on Mac Big Sur, the following shortcut appear (see the red rectangle in the following picture). This shortcut is in conflict with an other Macro shortcut. Is there any possibility to remove this keyboard shortcut ?
- Of course, one can say to remove the shortcut for my macro, but it is unfortunately a bit complicated, because all my keyboard has been reprogrammed so that I can write quickly on latex. And all opt+cmd+MANY KEY are command of the type \LatexCommand, and I think that TexShop interpret it as opt+cmd+\ , and thus, more or less all my macro shortcut doesn't work because this. I wrote to the creator of TexShop, and he told me that he can't do anything, because only Apple generate these shortcuts. If anyone has an idea on how to remove this, it would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: Shift-Cmd-M is assigned to `Typeset->MetaPost` so it runs metapost on the active Source file. I'm surprised your macro assignment  ever worked.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question (as written previously was may be a bit ambiguous). Maybe you have an idea on this problem ?

Comment: What OS version are you using? You might try creating a different shortcut for that command (spell it exactly as given) in the Shortcuts tab under Application Shortcuts. I’m not sure that will work since, as Dick Koch said, this set by the OS.